# Change Android Eclipse settings to ignore error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-errors, warnings

I reverse engineering an apk file and I edit some stuff in java files, and it gives me lot of errors BUT BEFORE THAT, I have already tested the original java files and resources from the apk that I reverse engineering without making any edit but it gives me the same errors which I had when I edit the java files and resources, is it possible to ignore all the errors in eclipse and export the apk to test or something to not have errors,
here is an example for errors :

```
  public class DataHeper    
{    
  public SQLiteDatabase database = null;    
  public File databaseFile;    
  public String databaseName = "data.sqlite";    
  public String databasePath = "";    
  Context mContext;    

  public DataHeper(Context paramContext)    
  {     
    this.mContext = paramContext;     
    this.databasePath = ("data/data/" + paramContext.getPackageName() +    "/data.sqlite");    
    this.databaseFile = new File(this.databasePath);    
    if (!this.databaseFile.exists());  
    try  
    {  
      deployDataBase(this.databaseName, this.databasePath);  
      return;  
    }  
    catch (IOException localIOException)  
    {  
      localIOException.printStackTrace();  
    }  
  }  

  private void deployDataBase(String paramString1, String paramString2)  
    throws IOException  
  {  
    InputStream localInputStream = this.mContext.getAssets().open(paramString1);  
    FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(paramString2);  
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];  
    while (true)  
    {  
      int i = localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte);  
      if (i <= 0)  
      {  
        localFileOutputStream.flush();  
        localFileOutputStream.close();  
        localInputStream.close();  
        return;  
      }  
      localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, i);  
    }  
  }  

  public boolean AddFavourites(String paramString)  
  {  
    String str = "UPDATE quotes SET is_favourist = 1 WHERE  _id = " +   paramString + ";";  
    try  
    {  
      this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);   
      this.database.execSQL(str);  
      this.database.close();  
      return true;  
    }  
    catch (Exception localException)  
    {  
    }  
    return false;  
  }  

  public boolean DeleteAllFavourites()  
  {  
    try  
    {  
      this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
      this.database.execSQL("UPDATE quotes SET is_favourist = 0 WHERE    is_favourist = 1 ;");  
      this.database.close();  
      return true;  
    }  
    catch (Exception localException)  
    {  
    }  
    return false;  
  }  

  public boolean DeleteFavourites(String paramString)  
  {  
    String str = "UPDATE quotes SET is_favourist = 0 WHERE  _id = " +   paramString + ";";  
    try  
    {  
      this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0); 
      this.database.execSQL(str);  
      this.database.close();  
      return true;  
    }  
    catch (Exception localException)  
    {  
    }  
    return false;  
  }  

  public boolean SaveQuoteOfDay(int paramInt, String paramString)  
  {  
    Date localDate = new Date();  
    this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
    Cursor localCursor = this.database.rawQuery("select * from qod LIMIT 1;",  null);  
    if ((localCursor == null) || (localCursor.getCount() == 0))  
    {  
      String str = "INSERT INTO qod (quote_id,changed,body) VALUES (" + paramInt + "," + localDate.getTime() + ",\"" + paramString + "\") ;";  
      this.database.execSQL(str);  
    }  
    try  
    {  
      while (true)  
      {  
        localCursor.close();  
        this.database.close();  
        return true;  
        new StringBuilder("UPDATE qod SET quote_id =   ").append(paramInt).append(",changed =   ").append(localDate.getTime()).append(",body =   \"\"").append(paramString).append("\"\" ;").toString();  
        StringBuilder localStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();  
        localStringBuilder.append("UPDATE qod SET ").append(" quote_id =   ").append(paramInt).append(",changed =   ").append(localDate.getTime()).append(",body =   '").append(paramString.replaceAll("'", "''")).append("' ;");  
        this.database.execSQL(localStringBuilder.toString());  
      }  
    }  
    catch (Exception localException)  
    {  
      localCursor.close();  
      this.database.close();  
      return false;  
    }  
    finally  
    {  
      localCursor.close();  
      this.database.close();  
    }  
  }  

  public Quote getNextQuote(int paramInt)  
  {  
    this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
    String str = "select quotes._id,quotes.body,quotes.is_favourist  from quotes   WHERE quotes._id >" + paramInt + " LIMIT 1;";  
    WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "next quote -->query= " + str);  
    Cursor localCursor = this.database.rawQuery(str, null);  
    if ((localCursor == null) || (localCursor.getCount() == 0))  
    {  
      localCursor.close();    
      this.database.close();  
      return null;  
    }  
    localCursor.moveToFirst();  
    Quote localQuote;  
    do  
      localQuote = new Quote(Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(0)),   localCursor.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(2)));       while (localCursor.moveToNext());  
    localCursor.close();  
    this.database.close();  
    return localQuote;  
  } 

  public Quote getPreQuote(int paramInt)  
  {  
    Quote localQuote = null;  
    while (true)  
    {  
      if (localQuote != null)  
        return localQuote;  
      int i = paramInt - 1;  
      this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
      String str = "select quotes._id,quotes.body,quotes.is_favourist  from   quotes WHERE quotes._id = " + i + ";";  
      WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "pre quote -->query= " + str);  
      Cursor localCursor = this.database.rawQuery(str, null);  
      if ((localCursor == null) || (localCursor.getCount() == 0))  
      {  
        localCursor.close();  
        this.database.close();  
        localQuote = null;  
      }  
      else  
      {  
        localCursor.moveToFirst();  
        do  
          localQuote = new Quote(Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(0)),   localCursor.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(2)));  
        while (localCursor.moveToNext());  
        localCursor.close();  
        this.database.close();  
      }  
    }  
  }  

  public QOD getQOD()  
  {  
    this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
    Cursor localCursor = this.database.rawQuery("select * from qod LIMIT 1;",   null);  
    if ((localCursor == null) || (localCursor.getCount() == 0))  
    {  
      localCursor.close();  
      this.database.close();  
      return null;  
    }  
    localCursor.moveToFirst();  
    QOD localQOD;  
    do  
      localQOD = new QOD(Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(0)),   Long.valueOf(Long.parseLong(localCursor.getString(1))),   localCursor.getString(2));  
    while (localCursor.moveToNext()); 
    localCursor.close();  
    this.database.close();  
    return localQOD;  
  }  

  public ArrayList<Quote> getQuoteByFav()  
  {  
    ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();  
    this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
    Cursor localCursor = this.database.rawQuery("select   quotes._id,quotes.body,quotes.is_favourist from quotes WHERE is_favourist = 1   GROUP BY quotes._id Order by body asc;", null);  
    if ((localCursor == null) || (localCursor.getCount() == 0))  
    {  
      localCursor.close();  
      this.database.close();  
      return localArrayList;  
    }  
    localCursor.moveToFirst();  
    do  
      localArrayList.add(new Quote(Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(0)),   localCursor.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(2))));  
    while (localCursor.moveToNext());  
    localCursor.close();  
    this.database.close();  
    WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "query: " + "select   quotes._id,quotes.body,quotes.is_favourist from quotes WHERE is_favourist = 1   GROUP BY quotes._id Order by body asc;");  
    return localArrayList;  
  }  

  public Quote getQuoteById(int paramInt)  
  {  
    this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
    String str = "select quotes._id,quotes.body,quotes.is_favourist  from quotes   WHERE quotes._id = " + paramInt + ";";    
    WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "pre quote -->query= " + str);  
    Cursor localCursor = this.database.rawQuery(str, null);  
    if ((localCursor == null) || (localCursor.getCount() == 0))  
    {  
      localCursor.close();  
      this.database.close();  
      return null;  
    }  
    localCursor.moveToFirst();  
    Quote localQuote;  
    do  
      localQuote = new Quote(Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(0)),   localCursor.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(2)));  
    while (localCursor.moveToNext());  
    localCursor.close();  
    this.database.close();  
    return localQuote;  
  }  

  public ArrayList<Quote> getQuoteByLimit(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, String   paramString)  
  {  
    ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();  
    this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
    if (paramString != null);  
    Cursor localCursor;  
    for (String str = "select quotes._id,quotes.body,quotes.is_favourist FROM   quotes  GROUP BY quotes._id ORDER BY body " + paramString + " Limit " +   (paramInt1 - 1) + "," + paramInt2 + ";"; ; str = "select   quotes._id,quotes.body,quotes.is_favourist FROM quotes  GROUP BY quotes._id Limit " + (paramInt1 - 1) + "," + paramInt2 + ";")   
    {  
      WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "query: " + str);  
      localCursor = this.database.rawQuery(str, null);  
      if ((localCursor != null) && (localCursor.getCount() != 0))  
        break;  
      localCursor.close();  
      this.database.close();    
      return localArrayList;  
    }  
    localCursor.moveToFirst();  
    do  
      localArrayList.add(new Quote(Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(0)),   localCursor.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(2))));  
    while (localCursor.moveToNext());  
    localCursor.close();  
    this.database.close();  
    return localArrayList;  
  }  

  public Quote getQuoteRandom(int paramInt)  
  {  
    Quote localQuote = null;  
    this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
    while (true)  
    {  
      if (localQuote != null)  
      {  
        this.database.close();  
        WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "random quote = " + localQuote.getBody());  
        return localQuote;  
      }  
      int i = new Random().nextInt(paramInt + 1);  
      String str = "select quotes._id,quotes.body,quotes.is_favourist  from   quotes WHERE quotes._id =" + String.valueOf(i) + ";";  
      Cursor localCursor = this.database.rawQuery(str, null);  
      if ((localCursor == null) || (localCursor.getCount() == 0))  
      {  
        localCursor.close();  
        localQuote = null;  
      }  
      else  
      {  
        localCursor.moveToFirst();  
        do  
          localQuote = new Quote(Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(0)),   localCursor.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(2)));  
        while (localCursor.moveToNext());  
        localCursor.close();  
      }  
    }  
  }  

  public ArrayList<Quote> getSearchQuoteByString(String paramString)  
  {  
    ArrayList localArrayList = new ArrayList();  
    this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
    String str = "select quotes._id,quotes.body,quotes.is_favourist  from quotes    WHERE quotes.body like  '%" + paramString + "%'" + " GROUP BY quotes._id " + "   Order by body asc;";  
    Cursor localCursor = this.database.rawQuery(str, null);  
    if ((localCursor == null) || (localCursor.getCount() == 0))  
    {  
      localCursor.close();    
      this.database.close();  
      return localArrayList;  
    }  
    localCursor.moveToFirst();  
    do  
      localArrayList.add(new Quote(Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(0)),  localCursor.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(localCursor.getString(2))));  
    while (localCursor.moveToNext());  
    localCursor.close();  
    this.database.close();  
    WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "query: " + str);  
    return localArrayList;  
  }  

  public int getTotalQuotesNoFilter()  
  {  
    int i = 0;  
    this.database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.databasePath, null, 0);  
    WriteLog.d("ThangTB", "query: " + "SELECT count(quotes._id) FROM quotes;");  
    try  
    {
      Cursor localCursor = this.database.rawQuery("SELECT count(quotes._id) FROM   quotes;", null);  
      i = 0;  
      if (localCursor != null)  
      {  
        localCursor.moveToFirst();  
        i = localCursor.getInt(0);  
      }  
      if (localCursor != null)  
        localCursor.close();  
      return i;  
    }  
    catch (Exception localException)  
    {  
      return i;  
    }  
    finally  
    {  
      this.database.close();  
    }  
  }  
}
```

Here I have a error that told me:

```
Unreachable code
in:  new StringBuilder("UPDATE qod SET quote_id =   ").append(paramInt).append(",changed =   ").append(localDate.getTime()).append(",body =   \"\"").append(paramString).append("\"\" ;").toString();
```

and I have this error in lot of files
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have return true in the line above, which makes it quit the while loop, that's why it is unreachable.

Then Java 7 doesn't work very well with android in.

Here is a thread about that to:
stackoverflow.com/questions/9098684/

Get latest JDK and it should work fine!

Comment: but why the application work good and she have this? and you know how to ignore all errors and export the app

Comment: What do you mean by "the application works goood"? Why would you want to ignore the errors instead of fixing them?

Comment: i have reverse engineering an application that works, but here in the java file that make me error, because i dont think there is error because the application that i reverse engineering work

Comment: Ok you mean that you reverse engineering an application containing this code? In reverse engineering you should be able too choose to ignore errors, maybe that is why.

Comment: You can in eclipse choose java -> compiler -> error/warnings

Comment: i did it but the error doesn't diseapear and i cannot export the app, can you help me with teamviewer ?

Comment: Iäm sorry I dont have team viewer. But are you using Java 7?

Comment: Ok, because apparently java 7 doesn't work very well with android in eclipse, because that is what you are using right?

Comment: Yes, i download the latest version or what ?